# How to Make Flex Spark Text fit within Given Dimensions

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex-spark

I have a multi-line Label, with user-defined text, that must fit inside some given dimensions.

```
<s:HGroup width="400" height="250">
  <s:Label id="myText" width="100%"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

I would like to adjust the font size of `myText` at runtime, depending on the content of `myText.text`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: as a possible workaround, you could snapshot the text into a bitmap. then display the bitmap and scale it to fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API call or even a straightforward way of doing this. The only way to do this is to iterate over font sizes and check if the text fits within bounds.

Comment: Thanks. Following the approach you mention, how would you make sure the new dimensions are recalculated between every iteration?

Comment: I don't think you can use a straightforward for..loop here. Maybe some sort of event driven system that waits for the resize event? I'm on mobile else I'd have tried it out.